# Database structure to log URLs and URL query parameters

Tags: mysql, database, url, logging

I need to log the visited URLs and URL query parameters to MySQL database for a website. The website admin also need to be able to filter URLs by value of the query parameter. For example he may chose to fetch all URLs which had `utm_source` query parameter set to "google".

At the moment I have the following structure:

**Table url**

```
url_id - INT
url_hash - SHA1 of URL
url - VARCHAR (1024)
```

**Table url_log**

```
url_log_id - INT (Autoincrement PK)
url_id - INT
visited_on - INT (timestamp)
```

**Table url_log_key**

```
url_log_key_id - INT (Autoincrement PK)
url_key
```

**Table url_log_value**

```
url_log_value_id - INT (Autoincrement PK)
url_value
```

**Table url_log_data**

```
url_log_data_id - INT (Autoincrement PK)
url_id - (FK links to url table)
url_key_id - (FK links to url_key table)
url_value_id - (FK links to url_value table)
```

The problem is the url_log_data is growing very fast. For each URL which has (say) 10 query parameters, 10 rows gets added to url_log_data table.

My question:

1. Is this there a better database structure? Can I improved anything in the above schema?
2. Is there library (or storage engine/database) that is more suited to this kind of data?

**Update**

An earlier version of the `url_log_data` table looked like:

```
url_log_data_id - INT (PK)
url_id - FK (Links to url table)
url_key - VARCHAR (The query parameter name)
url_value - VARCHAR (The query parameter value)
```

But this table is growing rapidly, and at the moment has 37 million rows. Obviously the table was getting huge and one of the reason was duplicate values for parameter key/value column. That is why we moved these two columns to separate columns in an attempt to reduce the overall size of the url_log_data table

Comment: what is in `url_key` `url_value` ?

Comment: url_key and url_value will hold query parameter names and values respectively.  
Example URL:  http://example.com?var1=val1&var2=val2  
var1 and var2 will be stored in url_key table and val1 and val2 will be stored in url_val table.

Comment: Here why ur creating 2 tables...it will also increase headache to keep linking between them. Why dont you create one table `url_log_key_value` with columns `url_log_value_key_id` as PK autoincrement , `url_id` as FK , `url_key` n `url_value`.
n i didnt get use of `url_log_data`...content of this table is duplicate? so according to me this table should be droped.

Comment: according to me u can do with only 2 table...that also in `3NF`.
tabel `url` with all columns as u mentioned + `visited_on` and another table is as i mentioned above `url_log_key_value`

Comment: Earlier the url_log_data table looked just like the url_log_key_value table you suggested. But this table is growing rapidly, and at the moment has 37 million rows. Obviously the table was getting huge and one of the reason was duplicate values for key and value. That is why we moved these two columns to separate columns in an attempt to reduce the overall size of the url_log_data table.

Comment: hummm...I will suggest you to keep keys and values in XML format. So that irrespective of no of parameters in URL you can have only single row in table for each URL.
else i am not able to figure out any other solution to this than use of `XMLTYPE`